# Unity: How to move functionality into smaller, more focused classes

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

I'm brand-freakin new to Unity, but I'm fairly experienced with C# and enterprise applications.

However, I'm struggling to find the right words to describe what I'm looking for.

Essentially, say that I have a `UserInput` class, and I want to break it up into a class focused on handling Camera movement, and another focused on interacting with the world.

This is in the context of a RTS / base building / city building game.

Say, for example, that my `UserInput` class looks something like this:

```
public class UserInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 newPosition;
    private Quaternion newRotation;
    // ... more stuff regarding the map

    void Start()
    {
        newPosition = transform.position;
        newRotation = transform.rotation;
        // ... more stuff regarding the map
    }

    void Update()
    {
        handleCameraChanges();
        handleTerrainClicks();
        // ... a lot more stuff later on regarding other possible interactions
    }

    public void handleCameraChanges()
    {
        // handle WASD inputs and move the camera
    }

    public void handleTerrainClicks()
    {
        // handle a user clicking on a building or something
    }
    // ... other unrelated functions regarding other possible interactions
}
```

The problem is that the only thing that all of these `handle...()` functions have in common is that they're tied to user input. However, I want to create sub classes to handle related tasks, such as a `CameraController` for example:

```
public class UserInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    CameraController cameraController;
    TerrainController terrainController;

    void Start()
    {
        cameraController = new CameraController(someReference);
        terrainController = new TerrainController(someReference);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        cameraController.handleCameraChanges(someOtherReference);
        terrainController.handleTerrainClicks(someOtherReference);
    }
```

Hopefully my example is clear enough. Let me know if I need to expand on it.

How would I go about breaking up such tasks into more focused classes?

Comment: Personally i think the whole MonoBehaviour concept of unity is a one way street to spaghetti town. For what its worth, the scripts will all run if you create multiple MonoBehaviours and they are active. So you could make various independent scripts to do different things.  However there is nothing stopping you continuing with what you have to have more granularity, have you tried to build the other classes? Also unity has a more modern approach to game design that helps with separating concerns in to entities jobs and systems, and efficient game design with dots.

Comment: @TheGeneral Yeah `MonoBehaviour` really scares me... I don't always want everything to instantiate and receive updates every freakin frame. However, I can't really keep going with the example I laid out. For example, how do I get a reference to `Input` to detect keys, or `transform` to move the `MainCamera` without inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`? I tried passing args to the constructors for the `...Controller` classes and got errors that lead me to the idea that Unity really doesn't want me to do that. What's a thoughtful engineer to do?

Comment: @TheGeneral Check my answer and please give me feedback!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add the `CameraController` (inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`) to the `MainCamera` object in my example. Then, inside the `UserInput` class I can do the following:

```
public class UserInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CameraController cameraController;
    private TerrainController terrainController;

    void Start()
    {
        cameraController = transform.root.GetComponent<CameraController>();
        terrainController = transform.root.GetComponent<TerrainController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        cameraController.handleCameraChanges();
        terrainController.handleTerrainClicks();
    }
}
```

But I really worry about the performance implications, and speghetti. This means that I have to add `CameraController` and `TerrainController` to my `MainCamera` (or something similar) and then magically pull it out of the air with `GetComponent<>()`.

There has to be a way to do this that makes get the warm-n-fuzzies!

Comment: This is pretty much how its done, also note you can make properties and link game objects and associated scripts together

Comment: @TheGeneral Could you please link me some good reading material on that? I'm brand-spankin-new to Unity and it's a very different framework than anything I've used in the past

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ControllingGameObjectsComponents.html look down the page to the linking game objects section. Also take a look at ECS and related technology,